# How can I manipulate chrome from outside app?

Tags: android, google-chrome

Basically I want to manipulate chrome from an outside app.  For example to change the search engine setting.

For illustration purposes:

```
(manifest)
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.chrome.permission.settings" />
(MainActivity)
com.android.chrome.setting.searchEngine("yahoo.com");
```

How can I access this functionality?
Is this possible?

TIA

Comment: I haven't tried anything real yet I wanted to know if it is theoretically possible.  But I think I realized it's not possible - that would defeat the whole sandbox between apps safeguard. Unless there is an API that would give such access.  Which I don't think exists as I have seen no reference to such a thing.